# PHP Version in HTTP header & Wordpress showing at 7+, however server is 5.4

Tags: php, wordpress, server, hosting

I'm having an issue with my Wordpress & Server

I've downgraded the PHP from 7+ to 5.4 as the theme that's being used requires 5.4

One of my websites on the same host is showing 5.4 in HTTP Header and Wordpress Dashboard, however the other website is still showing 7+ and won't show the installed version of PHP

- Running PHP version: 7.0.27 - Wordpress Dashboard
- X-Powered-By => PHP/7.0.27 (HTTP Header)
- Current PHP version:  5.4 (Cpanel)

The hosting provider has confirmed 5.4 is installed, removed all caching to prevent the old version being shown. Do I need flush something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your server configuration it is possible for different directories on your site to run with different versions of PHP.

Your Host might provide you with Cpanel PHP Version Management options. It may currently be set to use PHP in Web Root and all its sub-directories but someone may have **overridden this for a specific directory to run PHP7 e.g. wp-admin**. Check this and change if necessary.

If not the case then check your `htaccess` for your (web) root, Wordpress "root" (if different), and sub-dirs like wp-admin for lines like these

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

if you find one in a sub-dir which includes php 7 like above - then just delete the line; and hopefully it will then follow the site "global" PHP setting. In case it messes up your site make a copy of the original htaccess beforehand.

Comment: Yes it was similar to this however it was handled on server side but the issue was two sets of A records on cpanel DNS side which pointed to a different directoy with php7 and php5.4 - Thank you for your reply